Regular expression pattern in the string and then also remove the substring
I have a list of string which contains few set of characters and spaces in the beginning before encountered first three digits.
if the pattern found then I need to collect only first three digits from the string.
Example1:
String: "SEE 222 Newcastle NSW 203"
Expected output: 222

Example2:
String: "SEE TEMP 212 Newcastle NSW 203"
Expected output: 212

Example3:
String: "SEE TEMP212 Newcastle NSW 203"
Expected output: 212


Your post doesn't have clarity. Do you need "SEE" in the beginning ?

Which is it, VBA or Vbscript? Please only use a single one.

VBA would be a better option. Thanks

@MustofaRizwan No "SEE" required in the beginning

Sub TestExtractFirstThreeDigits()
    Dim testString1 As String
    Dim testString2 As String
    Dim result As String
    
    testString1 = "SEE 222 Newcastle NSW 203"
    testString2 = "SEE TEMP 212 Newcastle NSW 203"
    
    result = ExtractFirstThreeDigits(testString1)
    Debug.Print "Example 1: " & result ' Expected output: 222
    
    result = ExtractFirstThreeDigits(testString2)
    Debug.Print "Example 2: " & result ' Expected output: 212
End Sub

Function ExtractFirstThreeDigits(inputString As String) As String
    Dim regex As Object
    Dim matches As Object
    Dim firstThreeDigits As String
    
    ' Create the RegExp object
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With regex
        .Pattern = "\b\d{3}\b" ' Pattern to match exactly three digits
        .Global = False ' We only need the first match
    End With
    
    ' Execute the regex search
    Set matches = regex.Execute(inputString)
    
    ' Check if any match is found
    If matches.Count > 0 Then
        firstThreeDigits = matches(0).Value
    Else
        firstThreeDigits = ""
    End If
    
    ' Return the first three digits found
    ExtractFirstThreeDigits = firstThreeDigits
End Function


Please don't blindly do someone elses work for them. That only encourages the plz send me teh codez types. This question doesn't deserve an answer as it currently stands as it merely a listing of requirements.

Thanks it is working and best explanation in the comments. but not working on "SEE TEMP212 Newcastle NSW 203"

For example3: it is not working. Please suggest.
String: "SEE TEMP212 Newcastle NSW 203" Expected output: 212 and not working

"\d{3}\b" is working for me for all the patterns. Thanks everyone for your comments.

@Geert Bellekens I would like to confess that some time before I also replied to such an answer that "We are not a free code writing service, blah, blah, blah...". I received a message from administrators telling me that we "really offer free code services". It is good to tell to OP how a good question will increase his chances to receive a (good) answer and a link to a post describing what a good question means. Also, showing its own effort to solve the problem will motivate more experienced users to try helping him. Everybody  has been new sometimes and did not know how to behave here...

My bad will improve helping people.
